# about saving images on lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, aws-lambda, lifetime

so I want to produce images on-the-fly via a lambda function, accessable through a api endpoint. Since lambda is free to use, I was searching for a way to store the different images that I need for building the desired image. My nodejs package is already too large to store them in it though.

Now I've seen the possibility to store up to 500MB in the /tmp/ - folder, but given its name I'd like to know if this folder is automatically cleared and how long the lifetime of it is. Is there any documentation about it? Can't find anything tbh.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AWS Lambda is *not* free. It does have a generous [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) each month, but it has limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda is used to run functions on demand. They are stateless. The /tmp/ storage is ephemeral and to be used only while your lambda function is executing. When your lambda finishes executing, your access to /tmp/ is done.

There are many options for persistent storage on AWS depending on your requirements. A low cost option would be to use AWS S3, but of course you have many other options, like a typical relational database on AWS RDS, AWS DynamoDB for a nosql like store.

Also as another user has correctly commented, Lambda is not free.

Comment: An AWS Lambda function might re-use a container, in which case the `/tmp` storage is still accessible, but this cannot be expected nor relied upon.